# If I have an excel cell with a condition in it, can the condition overwrite itself with text so that the condition is not evaluated in future?

Tags: excel

I have cell whose value depends on the values of 2 other cells and time elapsed.

How can I stop it reevaluating itself on subsequent recalculations with different elapsed times?

Comment: you can't  do that with formula.  You would need to either copy paste the value back in or program in vba.  Formula are live and will always change if the inputs change.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I kinda expected to have to use a vba function, but none of my efforts have succeeded so far, though I have discovered several inventive ways to generate circular references.